# A basic DHCP client

Tags: c, networking, dhcp

I am coding a very simple DHCP client in C. I have trouble deciding whether it should use UDP or TCP, what basic commands should it support. I think it should be able to get at least DNS, SMTP, POP3 server information from server.

What else do I need to know? Is there a basic DHCP C implementation available which can help?

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't have trouble "deciding" whether to use TCP or UDP, you should [rely on the actual DHCP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131) to determine what protocol is used.  In fact, reliance on that spec will be more or less critical to implementing a DHCP client that does what it's supposed to do... since "what it's supposed to do" is defined in the spec.

Comment: Verbatim from the RFC `DHCP uses UDP as its transport protocol`